# SSRS in VS - buggy clearing rsRuntimeErrorInExpression Expression warnings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssdt-bi

When editing Expressions in VS2013 shell for SSDT (all patched), if a Warning is generated and then resolved (eg a conversion issue is then fixed in Design or RDL XML), VS keeps displaying it even though Preview/Run/Build is fine:

```
Warning 1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘<OopsField>.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

If I close and re-open the project, it's fine too - and of course, the warning has gone :-) !

Apart from being annoying, this obfuscates any other Expression or other warnings and errors during work. I can't keep restarting VS - it's a cumbersome beast as it is!

This must really trip up newcomers on first Expressions too (I've avoided SSRS until now, and it's not the easiest reporting system to pick up, although starting to warm to it).

Is there a way to get VS to clear these easily triggered warnings (likely applies to many other types)? Save/Rebuild/Preview doesn't cut it, maybe there is a quick way, otherwise it's an irritating VS bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this has been a **<s>bug</s> issue** in **Visual Studio** for over **10 years**.

Like most of the bugs in their products, Microsoft isn't going to fix this one. I think there was a **Microsoft Connect** opened once for this but was **closed** as **Won't Fix** or **WAD**.

[Here's one](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/649210/bids-sql-2008-r2-warnings-not-clearing) I found that said Microsoft couldn't figure out how to re-produce the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for conf @Hannover! Thought it might be, and see it's a long standing one then - have added my two penn'rth onto that MS Connect, good one!